# Opening an app from URL schema

Tags: ios

This may sounds crazy but just curious to know how a deep link/ URL schema reaches to an app to open it up in the device. Searched for an article but all contain how to make it work technically which I completely experienced, but could not find one how the handshake works.

If anybody can share if known, much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "how the handshake works"? What handshake? You know how to make it happen; you know that the system does it; what more can you want to know?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear; the question is how the OS directs the URL request to the app.

Comment: But what do you mean by _that_? Why would it have any trouble doing this?

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Answer (score 1):

The best information I could find so far on the subject is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking):

> Unlike the Web, where the underlying technology of HTTP and URLs allow
>   for deep linking by default, enabling deep linking on mobile apps
>   requires these apps be configured to properly handle a uniform
>   resource identifier (URI). Just like a URL is an address for a
>   website, a URI is the address for an app on a mobile device. Examples
>   of URIs that launch a mobile app:
>
> `twitter://` is the iOS URI to launch Twitter’s mobile app
>
> `YouTube://` is
>   the iOS URI to launch YouTube’s mobile app
>
> The format of the URI used
>   to trigger or deep link an app is often different depending on the
>   mobile operating system. Android devices work through intents,
>   BlackBerry 10 devices works through BB10's invocation framework,
>   Firefox OS devices works through Web Activities, iOS devices works
>   through the `openUrl` application method, and Windows Phone 8 devices
>   works through the UriMapper class.
>
> `fb://profile/33138223345` is an example of a mobile deep link. The URI
>   contains all the information needed to launch directly into a
>   particular location within an app, in this case the profile with id
>   '33138223345', i.e. the Wikipedia page, within the Facebook app,
>   instead of simply launching the Facebook app `fb://`. eBay's apps
>   demonstrate the use of different schemes by platform.
>   `eBay://launch?itm=360703170135` is the URI that deep links into eBay’s
>   iOS app while `eBay://item/view?id=360703170135` links into eBay’s
>   Android app

Basically the URL matching starts at the OS level.
iOS will use the settings in your apps plist file for a whole bunch of other things outside the app. One of them being the deep linking.

You declare your URL scheme in the plist, and whenever the OS encounters a URL matching this scheme (usually when user taps a button or link), it will open your app and pass the URL information on. It's then your responsibility to determine what to do with this information.

Does it jump into a profile page? A particular product? That's all left up to you.